# Issue while Integrating REST API in jira to create project

Tags: c#, rest, api, jira, project

I am implementing REST API of JIRA to create a new project using C# language.
I am using the following code:

```
NewProject objnewprj = new NewProject();
objnewprj.key = "key";
objnewprj.name = "Testing Project";
objnewprj.projectTypeKey = "business";
objnewprj.projectTemplateKey = "com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management";
objnewprj.description = "Example Project description";
objnewprj.lead = "admin";
objnewprj.url = "http://abc.co.in/";
objnewprj.assigneeType = "UNASSIGNED";
objnewprj.avatarId = 10204;
objnewprj.issueSecurityScheme = 10000;
objnewprj.permissionScheme = 10100;
objnewprj.notificationScheme = 10100;
objnewprj.categoryId = "10000";
var projectitem = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objnewprj);
byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(projectitem.ToString());

var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://jirademoseasia.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project");
webrequest.Method = "POST";        
webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webrequest.UserAgent = "xx";
try
{
    var webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = null;
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
     result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return "error";
}
return result;
```

It is working fine for REST client but in code i
am getting the issue

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Any help?

Comment: You might need to authenticate the request in order to create a project. Add a header "Authorization" with Basic authorization.

Comment: I have tried it also by adding this piece of code SetBasicAuthHeader(webrequest, "singhharwinder@seasiainfotech.com", "Seasia@123"); But the error is still the same. I am not getting what's the reason ???? Please suggest some other thing which i have missed.

Comment: Please paste the full http request if possible and/or the json serialized body of the request.

Comment: httprequest is same as i have mentioned in the code with one piece line of code as SetBasicAuthHeader(webrequest, "username","password") and json serialized body is :- {"key":"key", "name":"Testing Project","projectTypeKey":"business","projectTemplateKey":"com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management", "description":"Example Project description","lead":"admin",
   "url":"http://abc.co.in/",
   "assigneeType":"UNASSIGNED",
   "avatarId":10204,
   "issueSecurityScheme":10000,
   "permissionScheme":10100,
   "notificationScheme":10100,
   "categoryId":"10000"
}

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/project-createProject) says:

> Status 400 - Returned if the request is not valid and the project could
>   not be created.

I have created a POST request using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) to create a project with the same body as yours:

```
{"key":"key", 
 "name":"Testing Project",
 "projectTypeKey":"business",
 "projectTemplateKey":"com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management",
 "description":"Example Project description",
 "lead":"admin", 
 "url":"abc.co.in/", 
 "assigneeType":"UNASSIGNED", 
 "avatarId":10204, 
 "issueSecurityScheme":10000, 
 "permissionScheme":10100, 
 "notificationScheme":10100, 
 "categoryId":"10000" }
```

It gives me interesting results:

```
  {
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "projectKey": "Project keys must start with an uppercase letter, followed by one or more uppercase alphanumeric characters.",
        "projectUrl": "The URL specified is not valid - it must start with http://"
    }
}
```

I have also noticed that the JSON you pasted in your comment is wrong (there is an `;` after the url parámeter). Please review the server response in order to find a more detailed messsage about the project creation problems.